# Архитектура приложени

Tags: архитектура

У меня есть модели данных и репозиторий через который подключаются разные источники данных.  Данные вводятся через графический интерфейс. Где мне осуществлять проверку введенных данных? Как правильно делать ближе к источнику данных?

Comment: Например в валидаторах которые вызываются из контроллера, чтобы в модель поступали уже чистые проверенные данные.... на стороне клиента тоже надо не забывать

Comment: У меня как раз на стороне клиента.

Comment: На сервере тоже нужна проверка, как дополнение. Т.к. клиентская проверка это чисто для клиента, чтобы он не накосячил, а серверная - для ПО, чтобы никто не хакерил